# Coordinates of reflected point perpendicular to plane

Tags: geometry, vectors, plane-geometry

Having trouble with a part of a maths question, not sure how to tackle it in an efficient manner

The point A (2, 5, -1) is on the line L, which is perpendicular to the plane with equation $x + y + z - 1 = 0$

The point A is reflected in the plane. Find the coordinates of the image A?

I have already determined the coordinates of the foot of the normal, which is at $(\frac 1 3, \frac {-2}3,\frac 2 3)$

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal vector to the plane is

$n=(1,1,1)$

the parametric equations of the line are

$$x=2+t,\;y=5+t,\;z=-1+t$$

the symetric $S(x,y,z)$ is such that the middle is in  the plane;

$$\frac{2+2+t}{2}+\frac{5+5+t}{2}+\frac{-1-1+t}{2}-1=0$$

which gives $3t=2-4-10+2=-10$

and $$S(-\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3},-\frac{13}{3})$$